# Issues to convert SVG to PNG using Imagick

Tags: php, svg, imagick

I am trying to convert svg to png image using imagick.This is the code i am using.

```
<?php
$usmap = 'http://yatnam.com/demo/vh/card2_1.svg';
$svg = file_get_contents($usmap);
$im = new Imagick();
//$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$im->readImageBlob($svg);
$im->setImageFormat("png32");
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$im->resizeImage(720, 445, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$base64=base64_encode($im);
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
?>
<img src="<?php echo 'data:image/jpg;base64,' . $base64;?>" />
```

My SVG images contain many other base64 encoded images..These images will not convert properly if it is not in png format.

To understand the issue exactly, please browse svg url directly.It is a image with Pink background.Now run my code. See same image in white background ..

Please help me to fix this issue..Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the access to the SVG file? Or are you able to download/save it locally, then change

```
xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64
```

in the 1st `<image>`

```
xlink:href="data:image/png;base64
```

and reference your local downloaded and changed copy?

The other way to show what you need to change is here:

[image]

I'm getting then the following:

[image]

**UPDATE:** I'd like to say once more that the SVG file you provided as example has the pink background as `<image>` with **wrong** MIME type, as I said in the comments. The problem you describe occurs because of that, no matter how reliable the image source is. You can check it by copying the base64 value of the first `<image>` in the SVG, decode it and save and then open it with any editor, you will see this:

[image]

which is a PNG, not JPEG signature. However, the first `<image>` in the SVG has `image/jpeg` - check it.

Now back to your claim that you can't change all the files. What I can propose is parsing SVG's XML in your script and replacing all MIME types with the correct ones. Be aware that this will require quite a lot memory as SVG's may be large. Note the new code between `MODIFY THE MALFORMED SVG` comments

```
$usmap = 'http://yatnam.com/demo/vh/card2_1.svg';
$svg = file_get_contents($usmap);

/////////////////// MODIFY THE MALFORMED SVG ///////////////////////

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML($svg);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('image') as $image) {
    $encoded = $image->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->value;
    if(!empty($encoded)) {
        $binary = base64_decode(substr($encoded,strpos($encoded,'base64,') + 7));
        $info = getimagesizefromstring ($binary);

        $image->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','xlink:href','data:'.$info['mime'].';base64,' . base64_encode($binary));
    }
}

$svg = $dom->saveXML();

/////////////////// MODIFY THE MALFORMED SVG ///////////////////////

$im = new Imagick();
//$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$im->readImageBlob($svg);
$im->setImageFormat("png32");
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$im->resizeImage(720, 445, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
$base64=base64_encode($im);
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Comment: HI Alexey..Thanks for your Answer ...its working properly if images are in png format..i already know that ..But Need to work it in other format too..why its not working in any other formats..?? Thats is the thing i want to know..

Comment: What I meant was that very image you have in SVG base64-encoded has wrong mime type in the SVG. I.e. the SVG file is probably malformed

Comment: its just  a sample svg image for debugging..you can try it in any other svg image..if i am not wrong,same issue will be there with base64 images (except PNG images)..

Comment: I only meant the background in the SVG (pink with watermarked text), probably it has just wrong mime type in the SVG specified. Other images there were fine. The EU flag, for example, is added to the result image without any issues. What I meant that you download/save the SVG locally, edit there one line fixing the MIME type and use the local fixed version. If you have more files with such a problem, please share a few of them, maybe I understand the issue wrong

Comment: You can replace it with any other image string..hope you have SVG file .I just need a solution for this issue..

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your last comment. If you replace base64 code, that would lead to a broken image. What I meant was changing ONLY TYPE of the image, leaving everything else untouched

Comment: Hi i have to deal with so many other svg images like this..so it will be very difficult to change mime type in all files and also even site users can upload svg images..i can't restrict them to upload file with a specific mime type..